# Typescript when accessing object that doesn't have such property (possibly not exist)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

For example I have this data on JS

```js
const obj = { // never have 'c' property
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
}
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'] // always 'a'|'b'|'c' --> ex: [a,b,c] / [c,b,a] / [a,c]

const firstKey = keys[0]
const selectedObj = obj?.[firstKey] || 99
```

Now how to do it in typescript? I have tried it but stucked with such solution

```js
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type ObjKey = Exclude<Keys, 'c'>

type Obj = Record<ObjKey, number>

const obj: Obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
}
const keys: Keys[] = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const firstKey = keys[0] as ObjKey // --> I don't think this is right
const selectedObj = obj?.[firstKey] || 99
```

I don't think this is right, because by doing so I remove the possibility of runtime check on `firstKey` to have value `'c'`.
Wonder what is the correct/proper way to fix this ya?
I want to be able to access the `selectedObj`, but TS scream that

```
Property 'c' does not exist on type 'Obj'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to change the following line:

```
type Obj = Record<ObjKey, number>
```

to

```
type Obj = Partial<Record<Keys, number>>
```

Explanation:

In your question, you expressed a desire for TypeScript to raise a warning/error that the accessed `obj?.[firstKey]` property may not be defined which would force the developer to add a runtime check on it. In the example provided, we can see that all of the `obj` properties are defined and TypeScript will immediately complain about its use during runtime. The way to get around is to make all of the `obj` properties optional by using the [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) utility type. This will tell TypeScript that the property being accessed may or may not be defined, hence the developer will need to add code to use it.

Here is a ts playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oHICGaoB90CNs80BjNAWACgrRIoB5fAKxSgAUMAnYASwwBsAPACUIJAPacAJoLiIANFAB2AVwC2+CJwB82qlQlKEwKOOYAuBs1YBvKlCgZLARnn2o+SwCY3lAL4G4kYmANbwCJZyCADaALqs0ZhoimiEKWSx+pSGxlAAZjycxnKsYYjRAAyZ2UG5CBD8YsAQUowsqGZMAPwAdNEFRcBy8Th4AJxjQA).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but apparently it's still error even though I use type annotation (shown with your own playground link). Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I may have misunderstood your question, I thought you wanted an error to display in order to make sure the developer does a runtime check?

Comment: You can alternatively do ```const firstKey: Keys = keys[0]``` to show an error when firstKey is used on ```obj```. Does that answer your question?

Comment: sorry let me explain more, the `obj` will never have `c` property, while `keys` will contain `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`, but it could be `['a', 'b', 'c']` / `['c', 'b', 'a']` / `['a',b']`. Now I want to achieve `const selectedObj = obj?.[keys[0]] || 99`, but the TS scream because `c` doesn't exist on `obj`. I hope it explain well

Comment: So you don't want ts to show you that error?

Comment: Typescript will and it *should* complain given the logic expedited by your example. If you don't want an error to be shown then your example has the correct code.

Comment: Alternatively, is this what you could be looking for?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oHICGaoB90CNs80BjNAWACgrRIoB5fAKxSgAUMAnYASwwBsAPACUIJAPacAJoLiIANFAB2AVwC2+CJwB82qlQlKEwKOOYAuBs1YBvKlCgZLARnn2o+SwCY3lAL4G4kYmANbwCJZyCADaALqs0ZhoimiEKWSx+pSGxlAAZjycxnKsYYjRAAyZ2UG5CBD8YsAQUowsqGZMAPwAdNEFRcBy8Th4AJxjQA

Comment: I will update my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, where you mentioned that the object *keys* won't be changed, I would suggest you to replace this:

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type ObjKey = Exclude<Keys, 'c'>
```

with:

```
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
type ObjKey = Exclude<typeof keys[number], 'c'>
```

By doing this you are creating a typescript construct called *const assertion* that allows you to have an unmutable object.

More docs here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

You can then normally use a type annotation on the *firstKey* variable without receiving any error.

```
const firstKey: ObjKey = keys[0];
```

Comment: it almost works, but still error if I change the position of array into `['c', 'b', 'a']`. I will update my question for this case, sorry

Comment: If you change the position in the array then it's correct that gives you the error because keys[0] now is equal to 'c' and firstKey can only be 'a' or 'b'. So as a consequence you should also update the new index of the array like this const firstKey: ObjKey = keys[2];